# Can't run pg_dump unless It's from command line without "sudo"

Tags: postgresql, debian

I have a cron job running as "admin". In the shell script I am using pg_dump and getting a permission denied.

I don't get this. After all, from command line I do get this:

```
    $ whomi
    admin

    $ pg_dump
    (it works....)

    $ sudo pg_dump
    doesn't work. (permission denied)


    $ sudo -u admin pg_dump 
    still doesn't work (permission denied).
```

How do I make it work? Or better, how do I make the user "www-data" be able to run pg_dump without permission denied so that this will work:

```
sudo -u www-data pd_dump
```

Comment: `$ sudo pg_dump` -> `... FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`? Create role `www-data` in PostgreSQL, register it in the `pg_hba.conf` and grant to it appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts to this:

1. The user that is connecting to the database as, should be there in `pg_hba.conf`
2. The '`user`' is considered to be the linux username that you login with, unless you specifically provide a `-U newuser` along with the `pg_dump` command.

So for your query, adding a '`www-data`' in `pg_hba.conf` + restart (or reload) should do the job.